# How to get object location with javascript according to its parent div

Tags: javascript, object, html, get, position

How to get object location with javascript according to its parent div

For example :

```
<div id="ExampleDiv">  // bla bla position at the page

<img id="MyImage"/>

</div>
```

If we think ExampleDiv top left as the begining point (0) is that possible to get location of MyImage according to the 0 point with javascript ?

If possible How ?

Comment: Location on the DOM tree, or coordinates (x, y) it is displayed on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your go.

```
var img = document.getElementById('MyImage');
var top = img.offsetTop;
var left = img.offsetLeft;
```

Comment: yes this get that. so now the second part. i want to get mouse position according to the position we just found. how is this possible ?

Comment: Mouse position within the image or what exactly?

Comment: I am trying to make dynamic tooltip with javascript. So when the user hover its mouse over the image the javascript tooltip will be displayed according to the mouse position. you know just trying to make cool tooltip.

Comment: You are re inviting the wheel. There are so much free script library's which will do that for you. Anyway you do not need the position of the  image at all. the mousemove event will return x and y coordinates from the page i.e. `e.pageX` for Mozilla and `window.event.clientX`for IE.

Comment: DanielB it doesnt work. Because the div i am going to make visible via javascript is nested inside another parent div. I have master page and content pages. The div i am going to make visible as a tooltip is nested inside content pages div. So when i directly use the position i got via that method doesnt work. I need mouse position because i am going to make another div visible(the tooltip) and set it position. since it is nested inside another div it fails. You see it would work if the div i am going to make visible were not nested inside any other div.

Comment: the position absolute starts taking it position from the parent div. this is why that easy method fails. because the parent div position is not starting from 0 0.

Comment: You can easily move the div out of it's parent and have it as a children of body. As I said, you should have a look at library i.e. http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: How can i get it out of from its parent. that would solve my problem.

Comment: may be that helps you out http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/ but i.e. jQuery would do that with a single line of code for you (`$('#tooltip').appendTo('body')`).

Comment: then follow the link i've posted.